# Positioning UIViews within UIScrollViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have added 9 UIViews as subviews of UIScrollView with the below code:

```
-(void)constructedViewsForArray:(NSArray*)_listOfItems {
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_listOfItems.count * 160, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 100, 90);
    for (int i = 0; i<[_listOfItems count];i++) {
        UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc]init];
        UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 20)];
        test.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_listOfItems objectAtIndex:i]];
        [aView addSubview:test];
        [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        frame.origin.x=((frame.size.width+5)*i+5);
        aView.frame = frame;
        [_scrollView addSubview:aView];
    }
}
```

The view's are added correctly to the scrollview.But after scrolling the UIView's are not aligned. Please refer to the images below:

[image: 5px space before the first view]

[image: 5px space missing after scrolling]

The 5px space between the first view and the screen edge is missing after scrolling.
How can I set the view positions after scrolling.

PS: Paging is enabled.

Thanks for any help.

Regards,

iSee

Comment: Do you want to make scrolling finish by placing first visible subview with 5px offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that there need to be 10 px between 3 and 4, and 6 and 7, etc. for paging to work like you want it.

So changing the line

```
frame.origin.x=((frame.size.width+5)*i+5);
```

to something like this

```
frame.origin.x=((frame.size.width+5)*i+5 + (i/3) * 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are not noticing that the 4th column requires 10 px margin.so you need to add 5 additional pixel after 3rd column.

```
if((i%3)==0)
 frame.origin.x=(((frame.size.width+5)*i+5)+ (i*5));
else
 frame.origin.x=((frame.size.width+5)*i+5);
```

I hope this will help.